# ios Load a tab separated text to Dictionary and UIPickerView

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to implement a UiPickerView which will show the currency name and its symbol.

For example: United Stated of America, Dollars $

I have an entire list of 406 currency names containing the currency identifier, currency name and symbol which is tab seperated:

USD United Stated of America, Dollars $

VND Vietnam, Dong ₫

I don't want to show the identifier to the user, just the name and symbol. I plan to use the identifier for use in the code.

My questions are

1. What is the best way to store all the 406 currencies within the app. Is using the AppName-Prefix.pch useful for this? Or should I use a plist?
2. How should I load all these currencies in a dictionary with the identifier as the key?
   I don't think loading each and every identifier using code will be an efficient way?
3. Instead of using this way of showing all currencies to the user, is there any better way from the Apple or 3rd party API which provides us a list of all the currencies in circulation?

Just showing all the currency options to the user to select one seems like too much work...
Apple should include another Picker view just like they have for Date Picker which is just for currencies.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is using CoreData.
Save all of them in Data Base,with the currencyList as entity and  currencyName, Country, Currency ID as Attributes. perform a fetch request when user performs a query. Display just the required currency details